# Litecoind answers "getnewaddress" RPC request with "Method not found"

Tags: litecoin, daemon

After having compiled the Litecoin daemon found at:

```
https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git
```

and set up a username and password, calling

```
litecoin-cli -rpcuser=<username> -rpcpassword=<password> getnewaddress
```

returns the error "method not found" from the litecoin daemon `litecoind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to recompile the Litecoin daemon, making sure to call the `configure` script with the `--enable-wallet` option:

```
./configure --enable-wallet
```

From there, `make` and `make-install` will give you a binary that has the `getnewaddress` RPC method available.

This reason behind this is that - instead of just disabling the methods around using the daemon as a wallet, or throwing an error in the case they're used without the `--enable-wallet` compilation option - the methods themselves are not compiled into the binary at all. This is likely due to the use of litecoind as a wallet requiring an extra library - the Berkeley DB library - and the path of least resistance being to not try to compile that section of the code at all in order to avoid issues with referencing the library, but that's conjecture.

This should also solve similar issues in other coins forked from the bitcoin source, and for bitcoin itself.